# Redshift как сделать так что бы промежуточные таблицы занимали меньше места?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redshift

Использую Redshift + Airflow, нужно загружать из S3 различные отчёты, их 6 штук, каждый отчёт разложен по часу (т.е. за день по одному отчёту 24 файла) и это ещё с 5 аккаунтов. В общем каждый час я забираю 30 файлов.
Хочу распараллелить загрузку, узкое место - таргет таблицы (6, по количеству отчётов). Поэтому для каждого отчета и аккаунта создаётся промежуточная таблица, в которую выполню COPY из S3. А потом уже APPEND в таргет таблицу.
Проблема в том, что в отчетах много колонок, размер блока в Redshift 1 Mb и промежуточная таблица получает 5 Гб, при этом данные хранятся в довольно разряженном виде, при выполнении вставки в эту таблицу 5 таких же порций данных, прежде чем размер таблицы начинает расти.
Выглядит это примерно вот так. COPY и APPEND разнесены по разным таскам

```
-- Task 1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  schema.wrk_acc_report_h_13_dt_2023_08_07;

CREATE TABLE schema.wrk_acc_report_h_13_dt_2023_08_07 (LIKE schema.report_target_table);
                                
COPY schema.wrk_acc_report_h_13_dt_2023_08_07 (columns.....)
                FROM 's3://...../dt=2023-08-07/h=13'
                ACCESS_KEY_ID '12312323123' SECRET_ACCESS_KEY '12321313123'
                REGION '111111'
                CSV GZIP IGNOREHEADER 1 NULL 'null' TRUNCATECOLUMNS ACCEPTINVCHARS AS '?';
-- Task 2
ALTER TABLE schema.report_target_table APPEND FROM schema.wrk_acc_report_h_13_dt_2023_08_07 FILLTARGET;
```

В общем после APPEND таргет таблицы разрастаются до неприличных размеров, каждый лоад +25 Гб.
Можно использовать VACUUM для таргет таблиц, но операция довольно тяжелая и юзать ее посреди дня не особо хорошо, ну и долговато получается.
INSERT долговато.

Есть возможность как-то более оптимально создавать промежуточные таблицы, что бы они были более компактны и меньше весили?